# Coefficients of a linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab

Suppose I have a vector space $V$, with $\{\vec e_1, \ldots, \vec e_n\}$ forming a basis of $V$. Also, suppose that I have a vector $\vec x \in V$, which I want to express as the unique linear combination of $\vec e_1, \ldots, \vec e_n$, e.g. 
$$\vec x=
  a_1 \vec e_1 + \cdots + a_n \vec e_n $$

Is there any `MATLAB` code, so I can get the coefficients $a_1, \ldots, a_n$?

Comment: You can set it up as a linear system $Ea=x$ where $E$ is the coefficient matrix of the basis elements (here, the $e_i$ are column vectors), $x$ is your vector, and $a$ is the vector of coefficients you are solving for.  Then any of the linear system solution routines in Matlab would work.

Comment: Multiply by the inverse :)

Comment: @Paul, Ok, I'll check it out! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(sorry, I didn't mean to restate the top comment as an answer, I just typed way too slowly )*

Finding the coefficients $c_1 ... c_n$ for a vector $\vec{x}$ given basis $\{ \vec{b_1} ... \vec{b_n} \}$ amounts to solving

$ 
\left[ 
\begin{array}{ccc}
\vec{b_1} & ... & \vec{b_n} 
\end{array}
\right]
 $
$ 
\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
c_1 \\
... \\
c_n 
\end{array}
\right]
= $$ 
\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
x_1 \\
... \\
x_n 
\end{array}
\right]
$

So you should be able to solve this in MATLAB with the [standard solve operator](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html):

```
c = B\X
```

Where B is the matrix composed of your basis vectors and X is your $\vec{x}$ (all as column vectors).