# Is there a operation to a finite sum of standard vectors into a matrix where each row is one of those standard vectors?

Tags: matrices, vectors

Let $ \mathbf{e}_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $i=1, \ldots, n$ be standard vectors.

Let $ \mathbf{v} = (v_1, \ldots, v_n) =  \mathbf{e}_{i_1} + \ldots +\mathbf{e}_{i_k}$,

where $i_1, \ldots, i_k \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$ with $i_1 < i_2 < \ldots < i_k$.

I want to an operation capable of transform the vector $v$ into a matrix $M(\mathbf{v}) = \begin{pmatrix} 
\mathbf{e}_{i_1} \\
\mathbf{e}_{i_2} \\
\vdots \\
\mathbf{e}_{i_k}
\end{pmatrix}$

of dimension $s \times n$, where $s = \sum_{i=1}^{n} v_i$

**Example:** Given $v = (1,0,0,1)$, I want to obtain $M(v) = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0&0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

**my attempts:** I tried using matrix multiplications, $diag(v)$, Kronecker's product, but I couldn't get rid of the rows of zeros that appeared.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of operation are you looking for? If I understand correctly, this operation is not linear, and in fact it doesn't even map into a vector space, since the number of rows in the output may change depending on the input vector. Since the common kinds of operations you see in linear algebra, like the ones you list, all have output dimension determined by input dimensions, I don't see how you can write this operation in terms of them.

Comment: This question represents an intermediate problem that  I have. Taking the example to illustrate, my ultimate goal is, given $\mathbf{a}=(a_1,\ldots, a_4)$ and $\mathbf{v} = (1, 0 , 0, 1)$, define an operation to get $\mathbf{a}^* = (a_1, a_4)$. If I could obtain $M$ as described, I can get $\mathbf{a}^*$  by  the equation $\mathbf{a}^* = \mathbf{a} \cdot M $.

Comment: By "$e_i$ standard vectors" you mean the canonical ones? or just arbitrary ones?, also you say the matrix you want is $n \times s$ where $s$ is a sum from $i$ to $k$, but it should be from $i$ to $n$ right?

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. Given a vector $v = (v_1,...,v_n) \in \mathbb{R}$, you want the matrix which the $k-$th row is  the coefficients (in order) of the linear combination of the vector $(0,0,...,0,v_k,0,...,0)$ under the basis $e_i$ (canonical one), and if one row is $0$ you just supress it. I think that's what you want.

Comment: this post may help you https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1258117/coefficients-of-a-linear-combination

Comment: Thanks for reply @CésarVB. Responding your questions: (1) Yes, $\{\mathbf{e}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{e}_n\}$ denotes the canonical base of $\mathbb{R}^n$; you are correct, the sum should from $1$ to $n$ (fixed). (2) Yes, that is exactly what I want. (3) Unfortunately, the linked post does not help me; I already knows how to solve this computationally, I searching for a mathematical solution to put in a paper.

Comment: Is there some reason why it would help to write this in terms of other operators? Why not just write $M(v)$ as you have here?

Comment: @JairTaylor, I want to (formally) define $M(\mathbf{v})$ for any vector $\mathbf{v}$. So I think that a formal operation would avoid any ambiguity or misconception in the definition.

Comment: @RenatoFernandes I think your current definition (with example) is fine.  There's no need to define it in terms of other more-well known operations - and in this case I don't think that is possible to do, for the reasons in my first comment.  Just be as clear as possible and don't worry about having a formula.

Answer (score 0):

As Jair Taylor pointed out, "the number of rows in the output may change depending on the input vector". However, I think you can still define this operation.

The operation $M$ should take a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$ and it should give you a matrix of size $s \times n$, where $s \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$, so

$$\begin{matrix} M : & \mathbb{R}^n & \to & \displaystyle\bigcup_{s = 1}^n M_{s\times n}(\mathbb{R})  \end{matrix} $$

This way, $M$ has at least a good codomain.

Now, for every  $v = (v_1,\ldots,v_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}$, we define
$$O_{v} := \{v_i \in \{v_1,\ldots,v_n\} \subset \mathbb{R}: v_i = 0\}$$
and we define
$$\mathcal{N}_v = |\{v_i \in \{v_1,\ldots,v_n\} \subset \mathbb{R} : v_i = 0\}| = |O_v|$$ then we can say that $M(v) \in  M_{s\times n}(\mathbb{R}) \iff \mathcal{N}_{v} = s$.

Let $v = e^v_1 + e^v_2 + \ldots + e^v_n$, where $e^v_i = (0,...,v_i,...,0)$ for all $i \in \{1,...,n\}$ and $v_i$ is in the $i$-eth entry.

This way $M(v) =  \begin{pmatrix} 
e^v_{\phi(1)} \\
e^v_{\phi(2)} \\
\vdots \\
e^v_{\mathcal{N}_v}
\end{pmatrix}$, where we define recursively:

\begin{align}
\phi(1) &  = \min\{i \in \{1,...,n\} : v_i \notin O_v\}\\
\phi(2) & = \min\{i \in \{1,...,n\} : v_i \notin O_v \cup v_{\phi(1)}\}\\ 
\phi(3) & = \min\{i \in \{1,...,n\} : v_i \notin O_v \cup v_{\phi(1)}\cup v_{\phi(2)}\}\\  
& \vdots\\
\phi(\mathcal{N}_v) & = \max\{i \in \{1,...,n\} : v_i \notin O_v\}.\\ 
\end{align}

I know this is tortuous, but it's the best I could think of.